# ERROR in Can't resolve all parameters for DataService in D:/angular1/src/app/services/data.service.ts: (?, [object Object])

Tags: angular

I want to make deploiment for my project angular, it gives me error, I create a central service Dataservice, and a PostService extends from DataService.

hello, I want to make deploiment for my project angular, it gives me error, I create a central service Dataservice, and a PostService extends from DataService.

**data.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BadInput } from './../common/bad-input';
import { catchError,map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { NotFoundError } from './../common/not-found-error';
import { AppError } from './../common/app-error';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor(private url:string,private http : HttpClient) {}


  //methode get 
  getPostss(){
    return this.http.get(this.url)
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError))
    }
//methode create
  create(resource){
    return this.http.post(this.url, resource).
    pipe(catchError(this.handleError))     
  }
//methode update
  update(resource){
    return this.http.put(this.url+'/'+resource.id,resource).
    pipe(catchError(this.handleError))
  }
//methode delete
  delete(resource){
    return this.http.delete(this.url+'/'+resource.id).
    pipe(catchError(this.handleError))
    }

  private handleError(error : Response){
    if(error.status===404){
      return Observable.throw(new NotFoundError); 
    }
    if(error.status===400){
      return Observable.throw(new BadInput)
    }
    return Observable.throw(new AppError);

  }
}
```

**post.service.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PostService extends DataService {

  constructor(http : HttpClient) {
    super('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',http)
  }
}
```

**posts.component.ts**

```
import { BadInput } from './../common/bad-input';
import { NotFoundError } from './../common/not-found-error';
import { AppError } from './../common/app-error';
import { PostService } from './../services/post.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'posts',
  templateUrl: './posts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./posts.component.css']
})
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {

  posts:any[]=[];
  status=true;
  post = {
    id:0 ,
    title:'',
    body: '', 
    userId:0
  };
  constructor(private postService : PostService) { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {
   this. getPost();
  }

  getPost(){
    this.postService.getPostss()
     .subscribe(
       (response:any[])=>{
       this.posts=response;
    },error=>{
      alert('error innattendue')
      console.log(error)
    } 
    );
  }

  createPost(){
    this.postService.create(this.post)
    .subscribe(
      (response:any)=>{
         this.post.id=response.id;
         this.posts.unshift(this.post);
         this.post={
          id:0,
          title:'',
          body:'',
          userId:0
        }        
    },(error:AppError)=>{
      if(error instanceof BadInput){
        alert('c post deja supprimer')
      }else{
        alert('error inattendue')
      }
    }
    )
  }

  editPost(post){
    this.post=post;
    this.status=false;
  }

  updatePost(){
    this.postService.update(this.post)
     .subscribe(response=>{
      this.post={
        id:0,
        title:'',
        body:'',
        userId:0
      }
      this.status=true;  
     })
    console.log(this.status) 
  }

  deletePost(post){
    this.postService.delete(post)
    .subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response)
      let index = this.posts.indexOf(post);
      this.posts.splice(index,1);
    },(error:AppError)=>{
      if(error instanceof NotFoundError){
        alert('c post deja supprimer') 
      }else{
        alert('error inattendue')
      }
    })
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { ResumePipe } from './resume.pipe';
import { ProfilFollowerComponent } from './profil-follower/profil-follower.component';
import { RoutingModule } from './routing.module';
import { DataService } from './services/data.service';
import { CoursesService } from './courses.service';
import { CoursesComponent } from './courses.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CourseComponent } from './course/course.component';
import { EmailService } from './email.service';
import { FavoriteComponent } from './favorite/favorite.component';
import { PanelComponent } from './panel/panel.component';
import { InputFormatDirective } from './input-format.directive';
import { ContactFormComponent } from './contact-form/contact-form.component';
import { SignupFormComponent } from './signup-form/signup-form.component';
import { PostsComponent } from './posts/posts.component';
import { GithubFollowersComponent } from './github-followers/github-followers.component';
import { GithubFollowersService } from './services/github-followers.service';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';





@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CoursesComponent,
    CourseComponent,
    FavoriteComponent,
    PanelComponent,
    InputFormatDirective,
    ContactFormComponent,
    SignupFormComponent,
    PostsComponent,
    GithubFollowersComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
    ProfilFollowerComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    ResumePipe 
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    CoursesService,
    EmailService,GithubFollowersService,
    DataService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: please add your sample code to stackblitz then others can help

Comment: what is your angular version

Comment: Angula8. Version

Answer (score 0):

`DataService` is a service so you don't put random parameters onto its constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can't list `DataService` in your module provider list as Angular is unable to instantiate it (due to the `url` parameter).

You should be including `PostService` in the module definition.